# Get matched route before execution in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I need to intercept a route so that I can grab one of its parameters, and use that parameter to query a cache at the onset of the page request. I have two questions:

1. Is there a "matched" event I can listen for?
2. Is there a way in Laravel to check if a route parameter key `exists/isset`, or simply get all parameters from the route?

EDIT: Note that the `Route::matched()` or `Event::listen('router.matched')` feature requires 4.1.19 or later, earlier versions will not contain these features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like this:

```
Event::listen('router.matched', function($route) {
    $username = $route->getParameter('username');
    if($username && $username == 'heera') {
        // do something
    }
});
```

For example, I've a route like `Route::get('/user/{username}', 'UserController@show')` and the `url` for this route would be something like `http://blog.dev/user/heera` so, in the `matched` event listener I'll get `username` parameter using `$route->getParameter('username')` and if it's `heera` then do something, otherwise do nothing. The `$route` variable is an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Route` and you can use all the public methods of this object.

BTW, you may put it in your `filters.php` file.

**Update:** It's also possible to register an event for `router.matched` event using this:

```
Route::matched(function($route) {
    // Do something
});
```

Or this:

```
$app['router']->matched(function($route) {
    // do something
});
```

### Tested on `Laravel Framework version 4.1.19`.

Comment: I was able to add a filter to the route group I want to check, but I cannot get `Event::listen()` to actually hear a matched route event. In fact, doing a search through the source code doesn't reveal any such event being triggered anywhere.

Did 4.1 remove it?

Comment: Check `Illuminate\Routing\Router` which is fired in `dispatchToRoute` method and at line `991` you may find this `$this->events->fire('router.matched', array($route, $request));`. It works and I've tested it on my local installation of `Laravel Framework version 4.1.19`.

Comment: Check your version from `terminal/command prompt` using `php artisan --version`.

Comment: Apparently 4.1.18 (installed via composer) does not have a matched() method, nor a matched event fire. Updating to 4.1.19 resolved the issue. 

Pretty awesome change from 18 to 19!

Thanks for the help Sheikh :)

Comment: Glad it helped and also thanks for the accurate information about `4.1.18` and you are welcome :-)